# Jquery script not running in the while loop

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to display the div details on clicking a view button which are in a while loop  using jquery, but it is displaying only first record not displaying rest of the records, can anyone tell me to solve this  problem..

Here is the sample code :

```
 <html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){ 
    $('#view').click(function() {
    var user=$('#user').text();
      alert(user);
    }); 
  });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#content div{display:inline-block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$i=0;
while($i<5)
{
?>
<div id="content">
<div id="user">Street(<?=$i+1?>)</div>
<div id="view" style="color:green;cursor:pointer;">View</div>
</div>
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Multiple unique IDs are not allowed. Switch to classes.

Comment: IDs have to be unique. Use a class instead.

Answer (score 2):

`id` is meant to be unique (denoted in Jquery using `#`). Try using `class` (denoted in Jquery using `.`) instead.

```
<div class="content">
<div class="user">Street(<?=$i+1?>)</div>
<div class="view" style="color:green;cursor:pointer;">View</div>
</div>
```

And the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){ 
        $('.view').click(function() {
            var user=$(this).parent().find('.user').text();
            alert(user);
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i tried ur code, but i getting empty result as an alert

Comment: @lalith222 I updated the javascript portion, see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have set id="user", so you will get 5 div's with same id, so obviously it will print only the first one. So use class.

And to get the value of current element, use

```
$(this).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this its works for you..

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){ 
    $('.view').click(function() {        
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var user=$('#user'+id).text();
        alert(user);
    }); 
  });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#content div{display:inline-block;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$i=0;
while($i<5)
{
?>
<div id="content">
<div class="user" id="user<?php echo $i+1;?>">Street(<?php echo $i+1;?>)</div>
<div class="view" id="view<?php echo $i+1;?>" style="color:green;cursor:pointer;">View</div>
</div>
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```